# What is the purpose of dtplyr and the reason for the warning 'Please library(dtplyr)!'?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

On loading the latest version of `data.table` (1.10.4) I get this message:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4
...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data.table + dplyr code now lives in dtplyr.
Please library(dtplyr)!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Attaching package: ‘data.table’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    between, first, last

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    transpose
```

The message is not very helpful to explain why is it useful to use the `dtplyr` package. As far as I can see, as long as I avoid the listed conflicts I can use the `data.table` package normally? In fact, I can't `library(dtplyr)` without having the package installed, so the message itself does not provide very good instructions in this case.

Comment: I think before if you were using `dplyr` functions like `group_by()` with your `data.table`s, you only needed to load `dplyr`. Now the `data.table` specific code lives in a separate package, so they need to warn existing users. If you weren't using `dplyr` features to work with `data.table`, you can probably ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks @marius. I am still confused on which specific features are being referred to, as for example, I can pipe data tables just fine.

Comment: You can file your question at the project's github page.

Answer (score -3):

The package dtplyr is really performant, it could really speed up the calculation when my dataframe is larger than 10^5 rows.

What I did is:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)
```

Best regards